# How to fix interrupted console when using inheritance

Tags: c++

I'm a student and I'm just learning inheritance, so i do a simple example. But when i excuted my code, it just did the first statements and stopped. What's my fault? I have so experience to ask for debugging.

```
class people
{
private:
    string name;
protected:
    string phone;
public:
    string age;
    string setName(string name)
    {
        this-> name = name;
    }
    string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
};

class student: public people
{
public:
    string setPhone(string phone)
    {
        this-> phone = phone;
    }
    string getPhone()
    {
        return phone;
    }
};

int main()
{
student ict;
string name, phone;
cout<<"\nEnter name: "; getline(cin,name);
ict.setName(name);
cout<<"\nEnter phone: "; getline(cin,phone);
ict.setPhone(phone);
cout<<"\nEnter age: "; cin>>ict.age;
cout<<"\n==============================\nYour info: ";
cout<<"\nName:"<<ict.getName();
cout<<"\nPhone: "<<ict.getPhone();
cout<<"\nAge: "<<ict.age;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see your issue is that your `setName()` and `setPhone()` functions have a `string` return type, however they don't change anything. In general you should have these as a `void` return type.

When I made this minor change the code compiled and ran perfectly fine for me.

On that sidenote, your method/reasoning to have the `setPhone()` function in the `student` class is a bit odd, especially since the variable of `phone` is itself in your `people` class instead.

[image]

Comment: oh, that's right. But i dont know why using `string` instead of `void` makes this bug. Anyway, thank you very much! :D

Comment: Oh! this's my first time using stackoverflow. My english is even not good enough. Sorry for it.